# Select layer by name and select by expression

Tags: pyqgis

I want to select a layer by name and `selectByExpression` to select features.

```
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('OS_traces')[0].id()
layer.selectByExpression(f"{attribute_name} ='{OSnaam}'")
```

But I get the error code:

```
"File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'selectByExpression'"
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('OS_traces')` returns a list of layers which have this name.

`QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('OS_traces')[0]` is the first layer object in that list (if it is not empty).

`QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('OS_traces')[0].id()` is the "id" of that layer, which is a string, not a layer you can get features from

You should thus use the following to get your layer Object:

`layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('OS_traces')[0]`

Answer (score 5):

Your first line returns the layer ID, a string.
Strings are not layers!

Remove the `.id()` and your code should work.

Comment: you then probably need to break it down. Is a layer selected once the first line is executed ? (is layer None, or does layer have an .id() )